# Is there a test/statistic for the reliability of my data given my sampling?

Tags: sampling, nyquist, hypothesis-testing

I'm in a situation where I'm sampling blood pressure data over time (unequal sampling) to capture potential peaks. On average, the frequency of circadian blood pressure would be 1. But in reality, people will have spikes throughout the day depending on activities. Thus, I might find 2-3 spikes during a day, for example. Let's assume that my measurements are accurate. Is there a test for the reliability of the patterns that I find, or, the sufficiency of my sampling? Or maybe I'm understanding the problem incorrectly. Is there a way to know if these patterns I see are signal vs noise?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a known reference signal with an arbitrary waveform generator (arb) that is similar to the type of waveforms you will sample, and you can sample the signal with the monitor not connected but powered. For the first test you can compare the sampled signal to the reference for the quality and sufficiency of sampling and for the second case you can get a measurement of your noise alone. This can be done with an arb or other simulator that creates a source to your measurement that would be identical to the actual sensor. The second case only applies if your acquisition system is linear between having a signal connected and not connected (same gain, doesn’t go into compression etc).